# Is it valid to use the same private key for RootCA and SubCA?

Tags: cryptography, x509certificate, bouncycastle, jce

I have created via [XCA](https://hohnstaedt.de/xca/) a PKI where both the Root CA and the Sub CA certs have the same private key. This PKI creates a leaf (end entity) certificate.

I use three different cryptography providers to read the certificate chain: RSA BSAFE, IBMJCE and BouncyCastle.

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(PKCS12, provider);
ks.load(null, password);

X509Certificate[] chain =
            (X509Certificate[]) ks.getCertificateChain(keyAlias);
```

The RSA BSAFE and the IBMJCE returns the leaf certificate with the SUBCA and RootCA certificates. But the BouncyCastle returns only the leaf certificate.

Why the BC does not return the full chain? Which behavior is the correct one?

By googling it seems that it is not forbidden to use the same private key ( although seems bad practice ) beyond CAs

Comment: What is the point to share same key with multiple CAs? In the current design, your SubCA is useless, a waste of resources and space in certificate chain.

Comment: I agree with you. But as I said two out of the three providers return the chain. BC returns just the leaf. Not even the SubCa. And I am asking why?

Comment: It's bad practice *period*. If any certification body would find out that an organization is doing that, you'd not receive certification. Note that it has serious knock on effects on key management. All sub CA's would need to have the same validity period as the root certificate, for instance. And how would you invalidate a sub CA if the private key is leaked? CRL's would be useless in such a scenario.

Comment: In the Bouncy Castle case it could be a bug. It could also mean that it tries to detect if a self signed cert is used by checking if the public key in the certificate is the same as the one that signed the certificate. If you reuse the key then this is true and the chain stops right there. I'm not entirely sure if it is supposed to go like that though.

Comment: There is much information missing from your question. For example, what extensions are present in the CA certificates. [RFC 5280](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-6) contains a complex procedure for constructing and validating a chain.  Sadly, as is so often the case in beginner's questions, the lack of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) turns this question into a guessing game. If you'd like to improve your question, please say so and we can help.